# In jQuery, how can I get my counter to stop when window is not on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code. The countdown works, but the stopping of the timer when window is not on focus doesn't work. Also, I'd like to resume the countdown when window is on focus.

In my code below, the `$(document).blur()` event doesn't work, but when I replace blur by `click()`, it works. Is there any problem with the `blur()` and document?

```
var tm;
$(document).ready(function(){    
   function countdown(){ 
         if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds--; 
            $('#timer_div').text(seconds);
            tm = setTimeout(countdown,1000);
            }
        if (seconds<=0){ 
            $('#timer').text('Go');
            }   
        } 

        var seconds = 50;
        $('#timer').html(seconds);
        countdown();

    });
    $(document).blur(function(){
        clearTimeout(tm);
        seconds++;
        $('#timer').text(seconds);

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tm;
$(document).ready(function(){    
   function countdown(){ 
         if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds--; 
            $('#timer_div').text(seconds);
            tm = setTimeout(countdown,1000);
            }
        if (seconds<=0){ 
            $('#timer').text('Go');
            }   
        } 

        var seconds = 50;
        $('#timer').html(seconds);
        countdown();

    });
    $(document).blur(function(){
        clearTimeout(tm);
        seconds++;
        $('#timer').text(seconds);

    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried it but it didn't work. Here is my jsfiddle. Thanks a lot,regards

Comment: there is a problem with the `$(document).blur()`.. If i use click() instead of blur, it works.. is there a problem with blur event and document?

Comment: @alexx0186 use `$(document).mouseleave` instead of `blur`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var counter;
$(document).ready(function(){

function countdown(){ 

     if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--; 
        $('#timer_div').text(seconds);
        counter=setTimeout(countdown,1000);
        }
    if (seconds<=0){ 
        $('#timer').text('Go');
        }   
    } 




    var seconds = 50;
    $('#timer').html(seconds);
    countdown();

});


$(document).blur(function(){
    clearTimeout(counter);
    seconds++;
    $('#timer').text(seconds);

});
```